# Sending form via POST results in broken GET request on webserver (405)

Tags: forms, post, safari, get

**Situation:**

Sending a HTML form (method POST)  results sporadically in broken GET request on webserver (405). In the  browser is displayed "Method now allowed" (405).

The incorrect string in front of the wrong GET method looks like some form variables . For example `checkout=Weiter+%3E%3E`, which is the value-attribute of the submit button (`Weiter >>`).

**WA Log entries:**

```
"egoryID=vvXAqAFS1FIAAAFA6CQIDsbGGET /is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1268826926?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckout-ShowLoginPage HTTP/1.1"         405 92 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1268341878?JumpTarget=ViewRequisition-View" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 1016
"t_State=true&processLogin=WeiterGET /is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1269223568?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckout-ManageAddresses HTTP/1.1"     405 92 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1268974319?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckout-ShowLoginPage" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 1309
"ipTo=true&checkout=Weiter+%3E%3EGET /is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1270218168?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckout-ManageAddresses HTTP/1.1"     405 92 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1269355351?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckout-ManageAddresses" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 1223
"KpsHpPhxqCtk&apply=Weiter+%3E%3EGET /is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1271422613?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckoutPayment-Edit HTTP/1.1"         405 92 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/1270749634?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckoutPayment-Edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 1132
"egoryID=KzfAqAFSLHUAAAFARCQIDsbGGET /is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/499191000?JumpTarget=ViewRequisitionCheckout-ShowLoginPage HTTP/1.1"         405 92 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewData-Start/499170102?JumpTarget=ViewRequisition-View" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 1072
"rue&checkout=Bestellung+absendenGET /is-bin/static/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/-/de_DE/jscript/snippets/catalog/LeftPanelCatalog.js HTTP/1.1"                                     405 92 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewRequisitionCheckoutFinish-Dispatch" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 1086
"ponent=&addList=In+den+WarenkorbGET /is-bin/static/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/-/de_DE/images/ajax_loader_bg_white.png HTTP/1.1"                                                 405 84 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewDirectRequisition-List" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53" 813
"4E45&QuantityString=1&Position=1GET /is-bin/static/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/-/de_DE/images/ajax_loader.gif HTTP/1.1"                                                         405 84 "https://www.XYZ.de/is-bin/WFS/XYZ-DE-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewDirectRequisition-List" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25" 740
[...]
```

**WA Log analysis:**

- User Agent

  - mostly mobile Safari (Version 6.0, 5.1.1) 
    -- iPad und iPhone (Apple iOS; Version 7.0.x, 6.x)
  - sometimes desktop Safari (Version 5.1.1)
    -- Macintosh (Mac OS X; Version 10.6.8)
- different pages
- apparently only HTTPS (SSL)

**Question**

What causes this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Out of curiosity, are you viewing this log on a different operating system from the web server that is capturing this info?  I'm curious if there is an end-of-line termination right before each GET that isn't displaying correctly when you view the log file, which can happen when viewing a log on a system that uses a different method to flag the end of a line in a text file (say, LF versus CR+LF, etc.).

Comment: This is just an log extract of failed GET requests. The other requests are fine.