# Clients using `GET` requests for a form, even though `POST` is defined. is javascript iframe the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, http-headers, httprequest

I have two subsequent forms on my website with POST method.

The first page of my website `first.php` contains this code:

```
<form action="a.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="value" type="hidden" value="foo"/>
<div class="button"><label><span class="icon"></span>
<input type="submit" class="button-graphic ajax" value="Click Here"></label></div></form>
```

`a.php` can be accessed only via this POST request (otherwise user will get method not allowed 405 error)

Once submitted, this form opens `a.php` with an AJAX modal window.

`a.php` contains another form:

```
<form action="b.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="bar" type="hidden" value="none"/>
<div class="border"><label><input type="submit" class="button-graphic2 tracking" value="Continue"></label></div></form>
```

When a user clicks Submit in the second form, it will open `b.php`,
which can also be accessed only via POST request (otherwise - 405 error).

The only difference I can think about between these forms is that the second one contains a tracking js class (opening an iframe). this is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tracking").click(function(){ 
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.width = '0px';
        iframe.style.height = '0px';
        iframe.style.display = 'block';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.src = '/track.htm';
});
```

This is done in order to track a conversion using a third party script which is being execuated from `track.htm`

I noticed that I am having a problem with about 5% of my iPad visitors.
they open `a.php` properly with a POST request, but when they go ahead to continue and open `b.php` as well, about 5% sends out a `GET` request instead of the desired `POST` request, causing them to get an 405 error and leave the website.

I know that these are real human users as I can see some of them trying several times to open `b.php` and keep getting these 405 errors.

Could this be caused because simultaneously their device is using a `GET` request to obtain `track.htm`? and this is some glitch?

How can this be solved?

**EDIT 4.4.2015:**

Since there's a chance that firing the tracking script is causing this, I would like to know if there's another fire to fire it (or track that adwords conversion), without causing these iPad user to use "GET" requests for the form as well.

**EDIT 10.4.2015**:

This is the jquery code of the `ajax` class, that effects both `first.php` and perhaps `a.php`, as `first.php` is the parent frame:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajax").click(function(t) {
        t.preventDefault();
        var e = $(this).closest("form");
        return $.colorbox({
            href: e.attr("action"),
            transition: "elastic",
            overlayClose: !1,
            maxWidth: $("html").hasClass("ie7") ? "45%" : "false",
            opacity: .7,
            data: {
                value: e.find('input[name="value"]').val(),
            }
        }), !1
    })
}),
```

Comment: If you can know that, what does the GET request contain? Is it an empty thing? Or does it contain exactly what should be sent by the POST request?

Comment: exactly what the POST request should be (and thus the 405 error), as the form doesn't allow that

Comment: May be fire the tracker on the page load event of b.php? like that we can be sure that tracker is not interfere with the submit process.

Comment: @Hereblur  but I want to track only the events in which somebody is making the POST clicking that button). and not just opening b.php to see what's inside.

Comment: Beneficial to note: Colorbox uses `jQuery.load` which uses the `POST` request method if the data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Comment: @PhilipRamirez  The problem occurs though only with the second form, which does not use any colorbox code as far as I can tell (it doesn't carry the `ajax` class (like the first form does).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it shouldn't happen. The iframe created by your tracking script pointed to `/track.htm`, so there shouldn't be any `GET` request to your `b.php` page.

On the other hand, just thinking out loud here, there're a few scenario that could happen because of "real world" user.

1. The users happen to have bookmark the `b.php` page, thus causing them to open it using `GET` when they try to re-open the page using their bookmark.
2. The users tried to refresh the page `b.php`, then get warned about "Form re-submission". Being clueless as most real user are, they canceled the form re-submission, then click on the address bar and click `GO` on their browser with the sole intention of reloading the page.  This could also cause the `GET` request to send to the `b.php` page.

Considering the best practice when designing the page flow for form submission, it might be better for you to only "`process`" your form data in `b.php` and then return a `302 Redirect` to another page that show the result using a `GET` request. This will allow users to "refresh" the page without double submitting the form, and also allow user to bookmark the result page too.

Comment: actually `b.php` does exactly that - it processes the form data that was posted, and then sends the user to another page with a 302 redirect, thus it is impossible for a "normal user" to bookmark `b.php` or try to directly access it. also, I'm seeing the flow of requests in my web logs and when this happens, it is with first time visitors and first time requests.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but as it entails to the GET glitch but as things stand, ~5% of your iPad visitors can't sign up because the code only accepts POST and so far no one can figure this out. So I propose a change of strategy, at least in the mean time.

Preventing CSRF by only accepting POST requests is [already known to not work](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Only_Accepting_POST_Requests). Your choice of accepting only this request method as a means of security is what ultimately results in the 405. There are better ways.

One example of is using a [CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), specifically the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern).

The idea behind a CSRF token is that when you generate the form, you also generate a "key" which you tie to the form. When that form is submitted, if it doesn't have the key or the key isn't the right one, you don't bother processing the form. The Syncronizer Token Pattern gets fancy in that it changes the expect key each time (in the form field implementation, giving the `<input type="hidden">` field a new name attribute each time) in addition to the value.

Have your code in `a.php` generate a random token and
store it as a session variable on the server. Output the token in the form as a hidden field.

Before processing the request in `b.php`, ensure the token value is in the request data and ensure it has the expected value.

You can first check for `$_POST` data and if it is missing, check for `$_GET` data. Regardless of which array contains the data, if the data does not have a valid CSRF token, respond with a 4xx error.

If the token is good, consume the token and process the request. 
If the token is missing or is invalid, return a 4xx response code.

Another way would be to set your field names to random values each time the form is generated. So instead of `<input name="value" type="hidden" value="foo"/>` or `<input name="bar" type="hidden" value="none"/>`.

```php
// ... in an importable file somewhere ...
// Generate our tokens
function token($len = 13) {
    $chrs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_';
    $str = '';
    $upper_lim = strlen($chrs) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $idx = rand(0, $upper_lim);
        $str .= rand(0, 1) ? strtoupper($chrs[$idx]) : $chrs[$idx];
    }
    return $str;
}
function magic_set_function($key, $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
function magic_get_function($key) {
    return (array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION[$key] : NULL)
}
function validate_request() {
    $data = !empty($_POST) ? $_POST : $_GET;
    if ( empty($data) ) { return false; }

    // Ensure the tokens exist (hopefully not too costly)
    $field_tokens = magic_get_function('field_tokens');
    if ( $field_tokens) === NULL ) { return false; }

    $csrf_token_name = $field_tokens['token'];
    $given_csrf_token = $data[$csrf_token_name];

    // Get our CSRF token
    $expected_csrf_token = magic_get_function('csrf_token');
    // ensure we're expecting a request / that we have generated a CSRF
    if ( $expected_csrf_token === NULL || 
         $expected_csrf_token !== $given_csrf_token) { 
            return FALSE;
    }
    // After whatever other checks you want...
    return TRUE;
}

function fetch_data() {
    $data = empty($_POST) == FALSE ? $_POST : $_GET;
    if (empty($data ) { throw new DataLoadException(); }

    // Ensure the tokens exist (hopefully not too costly)
    $field_tokens = magic_get_function('field_tokens');
    if ( $field_tokens) === NULL ) { throw new TokenLoadException(); }

    foreach ($field_tokens as $field_name => $token_name) {
        if ( isset($data[$token_name]) ) {
            $data[$field_name] = $data[$token_name];
            unset($data[$token_name]);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

// first.php/a.php/b.php (wherever necessary)
// ...
$tokens = array();
// our csrf token
$csrf_token = token();
$field_names = array('value', 'bar', 'token');
$field_values = array('value'=>'foo', 'bar' => 'none', 'token' => $csrf_token);
// Tokenize errthing...
foreach ($field_names as $k => $field_name) {
    // and generate random strings
    $tokens[$field_name] = token();
}

// You NEED TO STORE THESE TOKENS otherwise submissions lose context
magic_set_function('field_tokens', $tokens);
magic_set_function('csrf_token', $csrf_token); // dup, but j.i.c.

// first.php
printf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s"/>', $tokens['value'], $field_values['value']);
// ...

// a.php
// Get the data... (POST/GET)
if (ensure_valid_request() !== TRUE) { handle_invalid_request(); }
$data = fetch_data();
// ...
// Tokenize errthing, generate a csrf, store the values, etc.
// ...
printf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s"/>', $tokens['bar'], $field_values['bar']);
// ...

// b.php
// ... You get the idea ...
```

It doesn't answer your question of *why* 5% are sending GET Requests but it does solve your overall problem on both a security and user level.

EDIT:
To specifically answer OPs questions in comments:

"(1) does this require using cookies? (a session means cookies right?)"

Read up on [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and look for a session library. Plenty out there, one heavyweight being Zend(http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.html). You can save to a database instead for protected server-side sessions. I made one similar to Kohana's.

*(2) I didn't understand the "another way" part - how does it differ from the method you described at first?*

First method is to just add a token to your form and look for the token to have the expected value upon submission. If the form doesn't have it, you throw an error complaining.

Second method dynamically sets the field names upon form generation AND adds a token field. Submitting the proper form data from a program, bot, or outside source now first requires fetching the form since they wont know what field names to use (instead of just posting data with set field names).

*"(3) most important, I am less worried about CSRF attacks, I just don't want bots/crawler to crawl into my forms, would this method prevent it from them, as opposed to humans? why? and is there an easier method to achieve that?"*

If you mean bots like Google/SEO/respectful web-crawlers, `robots.txt` exists 
for this purpose. robots.txt is a very simple text file that is placed in your site's root directory. You'll see requests in your webserver's access logs for a /robots.txt. This file tells search engine and other robots which areas of your site they are allowed to visit and index. You can read more on the (Robot Exclusion Standard)[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) on many (websites)[5](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

As the second link notes, don't use `robots.txt` to hide information. It is a public file and visible to anyone. Also, malicious bots wont respect the file.

I'm not sure if when you say bots you mean just crawlers or spambots (bots trying to submit data) and such. If it's crawlers, `robots.txt` takes care of them. If it's spambots, you can add a hidden field (hidden with CSS not html) with a common name that when filled out you know is invalid, you can add a captcha, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Does it mean I must use cookies on my website? how does this CSRF works - does it create the same random value and stores it both as a cookie in the browser, and as part of the to-be posted date, and in case of a GET request instead of POST, the `b.php` should check if the two values match, and if so let the request through? how does it prevent bad request? do bots / crawler never accept cookies (even Google's bots), and that's why it would work? or did I miss something here? thanks

Comment: Thank, I just saw you changed your post into an answer. few questions -(1) doee this require using cookies? (a session means cookies right?) (2) I didn't understand the "another way" part - how does it differ from the method you described at first? (3) most important, I am less worried about CSRF attacks, I just don't want bots/crawler to crawl into my forms, would this method prevent it from them, as opposed to humans? why? and is there an easier method to achieve that? thanks

Comment: Thanks for the information. regarding the bots, I basically mean bots that don't respect robots.txt and are trying to either scrape the website, or try to reach to the final destination page of the form funnel, I don't want to add anything such as CAPTCHA as it would hurt user experience.

Comment: However, It occurred to me now that even with this work around, the form wouldn't be process properly since the erroneous GET requests I'm currently seeing, never contain the parameters inside the requested url (they look like `GET b.php`, and not `GET b.php?param1=a&param2=b`).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the tracking on the callback of the original request to ensure its loaded?

Also you could look into something like ajaxFormPlugin by malsup

Comment: Can you explain? what's a callback? what original request? I'm not really a programmer, just using all sorts of knowledge I've gathered around. and what does this plugin have to do with my code?

Comment: After reading it again, I'm wondering if this is happening due to page refreshes by those 5%.

Comment: Have you tried disabling track and see if it works? Also if you are opening these in dialog modals, doc.ready is useless. Try wrapping the code in a timeout.

Comment: From my weblogs I can tell the users weren't refreshing, they were simply clicking the button. I found another thread of someone describing "sporadic problems" with iOS users [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815673/sending-form-via-post-results-in-broken-get-request-on-webserver-405?rq=1) without any answers. Looking at my server logs, it seems that in the period before using that tracking this wasn't an issue. so there's a good chance it has to do with this. but how else can I fire the tracking script?

Answer (score 0):

i would like to suggest to check the permission of your "b.php" page. Please make sure the page has "w" permission for all users. this is a chance for not making a "POST" request.

Comment: how do I check it? I never defined specific permissions so there shouldn't be any permissions set

Comment: Permissions are rules associated with objects on a computer or network, such as files and folders. Permissions determine whether you can access an object and what you can do with it. if you have a read only permission on a file then you can access the file only with a GET method. to check the permission method differs with OS.

Comment: My server is running apache, how should I check it there?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a workaround but if, as I suppose, you have a bunch of checks for the $_POST variables, if you receive a GET request you could try replace the POST with the GET:

```
if (empty($_POST) && !empty($_GET)) $_POST = $_GET;
//here the check of $_POST
//...
```

since we don't know why this ipads (...apple -.-) have the issue, and between GET and POST there isn't so much difference - at least if you don't need to upload files...

The only way a post form can be sent as get is using script (changing the method attribute directly, or replacing the form behavior for example with an ajax request, binding to the event "submit" another function), so I suggest you to check every script that run in the parent and the children pages.

Comment: I'm using POST in the first place since I don't want crawlers to send fake requests, thus 405 error on GET events is a good method to achieve that in my opinion. what should I look for in these scripts? as you can see the form doesn't have any class that is related to any script, so I don't know if that's the direction..

Comment: assuming you use jquery, you could look to something like `$('form').submit(function(){...})`, or `$('form').on('submit',function(){...})`, maybe `document.form[x]`, or every `ajax` you see. search for `get` word too. Hope you find a clue!

Comment: I've edited my question to include the jquery code that might be relevant, however I don't see there anything about the method being used, and also it applies to ajax class which apperas only on `first.php`... do you see anything there that might cause this?

Comment: no, I don't see any problem for that code. As said in philip ramirez's comment, `colorbox` will use POST since you set the `data` parameter as an object. anyway, since this code is placed only on `first.php`, it shouldn't affect opened iframes. Sorry if i'm not of great help... second: there's no difference between get and post in therm of protection by hackers (the first is only faster for manual hack)... the only thing you can use is the `robots.txt` and the `rel='nofollow'` attribute to "ask" some crawlers to be gone from the entire site or not follow a specified link.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax call doesn't contain `method: "POST"`. This can be the cause.

Comment: the no POST problem occurs with the second form, and the first one, thus the ajax call isn't relevant as far as I can tell.