# Exclude certain user-agent, who use GET requests, from a Method not allowed Error (Set when method is not POST)?

Tags: php

I have this form (`a.php`):

```
<form action="b.php" method="POST">
<input name="destination" type="hidden" value="option1"/>
<input type="submit" value="continue"></form>
```

I don't want malicious bots to to crawl `b.php` and its destination pages, thus I set `b.php` to process `a.php` only if the requested Method was indeed POST:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {

    header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');
    include '405-error-message.php';
    exit(); }

else {

$url = "http://www.example.com/error.html"; // default destination page

if(isset($_POST['destination'])){

    switch ($_POST['destination']) {

    case "option1":
        $url = "http://www.example.com/option1.html";
        break;

    case "option2":
        $url = "http://www.example.com/option2.html";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://www.example.com/error.html";
    }
}

header("Location: $url", true, 302);

}
?>
```

However, I found out that about 5% of my iPad visitors are using a GET instead of POST and therefore get blocked. [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507315/clients-using-get-requests-for-a-form-even-though-post-is-defined-is-javas) I've tried to find out the reason for this, to no avail.

So I've decided that for the time being, I would exclude iPad user agents from that 405 rule - I want `b.php` to keep checking for POST requests from iPad users too, but add a rule that if it gets a GET requests, it will process them as well.

Note that such a code should also address the `isset/switch` values, which I'm not sure how to do either.

Also, I'm assuming here that the GET requests coming from the problematic iPad devices, DO contain the necessary values of the `a.php` form, which I hope is true.

Comment: I don't believe that iPad users are using `GET` when they submit the form. If that were true they would have problems with thousands of web sites.

Comment: Check your PHP access log. If the erroneous GET requests contain the parameters, you'll see them in the URL.

Comment: You would get that problem if you re-visit after the first time. Not only iPad users will have problems accessing your website like that.

Comment: @Barmar If you would read the thread I've mentioned you will see a possible cause for this behavior, that couldn't be resolved so far.

Comment: and if the bots figure out that ipads are allowed, then they'll simply start saying "I'm an ipad!" and get in anyways...

Comment: @MarcB this is a chance I can take...

Comment: @Barmar currently in my raw access logs I don't see that the GET requests contain the parameters in the url (only `b.php`, and not `b.php?destination=option1`), does that mean that the answer for this question won't solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, it means that. As mentioned in the answer to your other questions, those erroneous requests are not coming from users submitting the form, but simply opening the URL of the form action.

Comment: BTW, if you want to code your page so it accepts parameters with both GET and POST, you can use `$_REQUEST`. It combines both arrays.

Comment: I see :( any idea then what I can do to make it work for these iPad users?